# OSX crashing on Bluetooth serial open/close cycle

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth, serial-port, pyserial

I have a Bluetooth device ([a RN-42](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEwQFjAE&url=http://www.rovingnetworks.com/products/RN42&ei=8AaqUYDuJKGC4ATh64DwAQ&usg=AFQjCNEvzQRw4vlP0op7jKZmB6HLSZtNSQ&sig2=9CqFbHlCo9GgTGMMlghwnw&bvm=bv.47244034,d.bGE)) paired with a Mac (Macbook Pro 2010 model, Mountain Lion). I am opening a serial port against it at regular intervals.
What happens is that I end up with a kernel panic after a while (usually less than an hour) of connecting/disconnecting. The kernel panic report always points at a Bluetooth kernel extension

My question would be, am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?... Or is the Bluetooth support in OSX somewhat broken?

This code does the opening/closing. Serial being [Pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/):

```
import serial 
import time
while True:
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial("/dev/tty.RN42-E2C1-SPP", 9600, timeout = 3)
        ser.write("?\r")
        print ser.readline()
        ser.close()
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

**Note:** I do connect from different devices, so I do need to close the port.
**Note:** It doesn't seem to crash if I take away any other Bluetooth connections (such as audio)

Comment: What bluetooth-serial driver are you using for this?

Comment: @gaige I am using whatever ships with Mountain Lion and talking to a generic Bluetooth device, no optional drivers installed.